# mysqli_fetch_array error Undefined offset:1

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 5 sp_id ,$count is giving 5 too .But when I check the size through mysqli_fetch_array it gives me size 2 and prints only 1  and gives error Undefined offset:1 further.And I want to get the values of ids , i mean print the ids through for loop .

```
     $selectId="Select sp_id from stitchedproduct";
$selectIdR = mysqli_query($connection,$selectId) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($selectIdR);
$fetchedResult= mysqli_fetch_array($selectIdR);

for ($i=0;$i < $count; $i++) {
print $fetchedResult[$i];
     }
```

Comment: try print_r($fetchedResult);

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$fetchedResult= mysqli_fetch_array($selectIdR);

for ($i=0;$i < $count; $i++) {
    print $fetchedResult[$i];
}
```

with

```
while( $fetchedResult= mysqli_fetch_array($selectIdR)) {
    print $fetchedResult['sp_id'];
}
```